# iPhone:- Wants to autoLogin through saved credentials in Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app i have to login inside Facebook without using login page and directly move onto home screen of Facebook.

i have searched a lot but i didn't get anything.......

```
@interface Facebook (MyApp)
- (void)myAuthorize:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate;
@end

@implementation Facebook (MyApp)

- (void)myAuthorize:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate {
  _permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", *(whatever you need)*, nil] retain];
  _sessionDelegate = delegate;
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]; // force in app auth
}

@end





    Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:MY_APP_FB_ID];
     [facebook myAuthorize:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.  Because if you do this you will get the password for all the users and you can hack their account.  So, FB does not allow this.

Comment: in my application i am not storing any one password in database its from web service that i wants to fill the credentials....thanks for response....

Comment: Yes, I dont actually I mean that you are storing.. but some ppl can store.. So,  FB dont allow it..  We had similar requirement and in our research we found that it is not possible...